# How to capture specific fields from elasticsearch and convert into a pandas dataframe

Tags: python, json, pandas, elasticsearch

Using query `http://abc:9200/abc/_search?q=aid:123` I'm able to get the following result. First thing I would like to filter is 'aid' and then capture only the needed fields ("act_timestamp", "act_type", "mod_path", "mod_size) along with "procguid" and put them together in a table.

Providing the exact Input and Output below:

Input:

```
{
"took": 95,
"timed_out": false,
"_shards": {
    "total": 5,
    "successful": 5,
    "skipped": 0,
    "failed": 0
},
"hits": {
    "total": 4,
    "max_score": 1,
    "hits": [
        {
            "_index": "xxx",
            "_type": "_doc",
            "_id": "xxxxxxxxx",
            "_score": 1,
            "_source": {
                "aid": 123,
                "activity": [
                    {
                        "act_timestamp": 1549437711762,
                        "act_type": "reg_act",
                        "reg_action": "writeval",
                        "reg_action_typeid": 3
                    },
                    {
                        "act_timestamp": 1549437714812,
                        "act_type": "reg_act",
                        "reg_action": "writeval",
                        "reg_action_typeid": 3
                    },
                    {
                        "act_timestamp": 1549437711418,
                        "act_type": "child_proc",
                        "child_name": "audiodg.exe"
                    }
                ],
                "event_timestamp": 1549437712183,
                "tid": "demo",
                "procguid": "11111",
                "doc_id": 1000881655327721
            }
        },
        {
            "_index": "xxx",
            "_type": "_doc",
            "_id": "xxxxxxxxx",
            "_score": 1,
            "_source": {
                "aid": 123,
                "activity": [
                    {
                        "act_timestamp": 1549437977317,
                        "act_type": "mod_load",
                        "mod_path": "path1",
                        "mod_size": 32768
                    },
                    {
                        "act_timestamp": 1549437977390,
                        "act_type": "mod_load",
                        "mod_path": "path2",
                        "mod_size": 667648
                    },
                    {
                        "act_timestamp": 1549437977399,
                        "act_type": "reg_act",
                        "reg_action": "writeval",
                        "reg_action_typeid": 3
                    },
                    {
                        "act_timestamp": 1549437977407,
                        "act_type": "child_proc",
                        "child_name": "conhost.exe"
                    }
                ],
                "event_timestamp": 1549437977406,
                "tid": "demo",
                "procguid": "22222",
                "doc_id": 1010298962848944
            }
        },
        {
            "_index": "xxx",
            "_type": "_doc",
            "_id": "xxxxxxxxx",
            "_score": 1,
            "_source": {
                "aid": 123,
                "activity": [
                    {
                        "act_timestamp": 1549437772915,
                        "act_type": "mod_load",
                        "mod_path": "path3",
                        "mod_size": 409600
                    },
                    {
                        "act_timestamp": 1549437772940,
                        "act_type": "mod_load",
                        "mod_path": "path4",
                        "mod_size": 937984
                    },
                    {
                        "act_timestamp": 1549437953405,
                        "act_type": "child_proc",
                        "child_name": "conhost.exe"
                    }
                ],
                "event_timestamp": 1549437953405,
                "tid": "demo",
                "procguid": "22222",
                "doc_id": 1007612603810098
            }
        },
        {
            "_index": "xxx",
            "_type": "_doc",
            "_id": "xxxxxxxxx",
            "_score": 1,
            "_source": {
                "aid": 123,
                "activity": [
                    {
                        "act_timestamp": 1549437848842,
                        "act_type": "mod_load",
                        "mod_path": "path5",
                        "mod_size": 1679360
                    },
                    {
                        "act_timestamp": 1549437848844,
                        "act_type": "mod_load",
                        "mod_path": "path6",
                        "mod_size": 2121728
                    },
                    {
                        "act_timestamp": 1549437848864,
                        "act_type": "mod_load",
                        "mod_path": "path7",
                        "mod_size": 266240
                    },
                    {
                        "act_timestamp": 1549437849590,
                        "act_type": "reg_act",
                        "reg_action": "writeval",
                        "reg_action_typeid": 3
                    },
                    {
                        "act_timestamp": 1549437953418,
                        "act_type": "child_proc",
                        "child_name": "wpscloudsvr.exe"
                    }
                ],
                "event_timestamp": 1549437953417,
                "tid": "demo",
                "procguid": "33333",
                "doc_id": 1007725853753652
            }
        }]}}
```

And I want Output as follows:

```
procguid   act_type   mod_path      mod_size

22222     mod_load     path1        32768
22222     mod_load     path2        667648
22222     mod_load     path3        409600
22222     mod_load     path4        937984
33333     mod_load     path5        1679360
33333     mod_load     path6        2121728
33333     mod_load     path7        266240
```

So is there any way I can convert these mass number of elasticsearch documents into a dataframe like this?

Any suggestions/solution codes? I've been stuck for a long time as I'm new to elasticsearch/json.

EDIT: There are some blocks where "activity" field is also missing while having "procguid"

Comment: Maybe you should check out https://github.com/onesuper/pandasticsearch. You can query and filter the data, and then transform it to a pandas DataFrame in the package.

Comment: @user3212593 Alright I'll look into it, it seems interesting. thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could break your task into parts. At first you focus on

```
df = pd.io.json.json_normalize(d['hits']['hits'])
```

This has the columns

```
['_id', '_index', '_score', '_source.activity', '_source.aid', '_source.doc_id', '_source.event_timestamp', '_source.procguid', '_source.tid', '_type']
```

Now you can iterate through column `_source.activity`, convert each cell to a DataFrame and collect them:

```
dfs = []
for idx, cell in df['_source.activity'].iteritems():
    df_activity = pd.io.json.json_normalize(cell)
    df_activity['procguid'] = df.loc[idx, '_source.procguid']
    dfs.append(df_activity)
```

Putting all together leads (hopefully) to the expected result:

```
pd.concat(dfs, sort=False, ignore_index=True)[['procguid', 'act_type', 'mod_path', 'mod_size']]
```